# sorted value is not geting properly displayed in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The code is working properly but when I add more than one value for a particular alphabet it gets repeated. If there is a single value for that alphabet the data is displayed properly - where am I going wrong?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PeopleModal *dislist = [[PeopleModal alloc]init];
    [dislist getAll];

    personarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [personarray addObjectsFromArray:dislist.Peoplelistarray];
    //short the personarray value:
    NSSortDescriptor *asortDescriptor;
    asortDescriptor=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"FirstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:asortDescriptor];
    [self.personarray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //---create the index---
    Frstname = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //check
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *row in personarray) {
        [tempArray addObject:[row valueForKey:@"FirstName"]];

        for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]-1; i++){
            char alphabet = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
            NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
            if (![Frstname containsObject:uniChar]){  
                [Frstname addObject:uniChar];           
            }
        }

    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.

    return [Frstname count];

}

//---set the title for each section---
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [Frstname objectAtIndex:section];

}

//---set the index for the table---
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return Frstname;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (isSearchOn) {
        return [searchResult count];
    } else{
//return personarray.count;
    //---get the letter in each section; e.g., A, B, C, etc.---
    NSString *alphabet = [Frstname objectAtIndex:section];
    //---get all FirstName beginning with the letter---beginswith
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.FirstName beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSArray *Names = [personarray  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    //---return the number of Names beginning with the letter---
    return [Names count];
    }

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [Mytableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if (isSearchOn) {
        NSString *cellValue = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    }
    else {

    //---get the letter in the current section---
    NSString* alphabet = [Frstname objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.FirstName beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    //[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    //NSArray *Names = [[personarray valueForKey:@"FirstName"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSArray *Names = [personarray  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    //NSArray *lastNames = [[personarray valueForKey:@"LastName"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if ([Names count]>0) {
        //---extract the relevant firstname from the Names object---


        PeopleModal *locallist = [Names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = locallist.FirstName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=locallist.LastName;           
    }   

    }


    return cell;





}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and leave the first lines out of the code block? This is tough to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you are using containsObject and that will allways return false because the id of that object is a new NSString so your code adds the same NSString value in the Array. Try something like this:

```
NSArray *duplicates = [Frstname filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet]];
if ([duplicates count] == 0) {
    [Frstname addObject:uniChar]
}
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (NSDictionary *row in personarray) {
  [tempArray addObject:[row valueForKey:@"FirstName"]];
  
  for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]-1; i++){
   char alphabet = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
   NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
   NSArray *duplicates = [Frstname filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet]];
   //if (![Frstname containsObject:uniChar])
   if ([duplicates count] == 0){  
    [Frstname addObject:uniChar];

Comment: i try according to u i get error this  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "%c"'

Comment: sorry.. like this `    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] '%c'", alphabet];`

Comment: friend i try same but it not display any value in my code where this put please tell me i try in cellforrow at indexpath also but not happen any thing

Comment: i added a new answer as the comments do not show the code properly. Also would be really helpful if you describe what you are trying to do, because i still do not have clear if you want to add the first letter or every letter from the first name, anyway i think the new answer will point you in the right direction.. hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

have you debug your code??
you are getting the repeated values because of these lines

```
  for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]-1; i++){
        char alphabet = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
        NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
        if (![Frstname containsObject:uniChar]){  
            [Frstname addObject:uniChar];

        }
```

here you are running a for loop in side another for loop.so this will get called for each and every iteration.
instead of the for loop use

```
  char alphabet = [[[row valueForKey:@"FirstName"] characterAtIndex:0];
    NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
    if (![Frstname containsObject:uniChar]){  
        [Frstname addObject:uniChar];
```

i hope you are writing the code to get the unique first characters...

Comment: have you remove the inner for loop?

Comment: so what are you missing?? are yor getting repeated sections or repeated values in the section??

Comment: and one more thing is your PeopleModel is NSDictionary's sub class?? why because you are using (NSDictionary *row in personarray) in view did load and  PeopleModal *locallist in table view cell for row at index..

Comment: if i write small letter then it not repeat same name again if iwrite both small and capital letter for same name for eg :pradeep,Pradeep the he will give two time print on cell

Comment: that is obvious...for that you need to write your own logic like store only capital or small case letters only using [uniChar capitalised string] and while getting the array you need to write predicate for both capital and small letters...

Comment: that will work for your logic... but what i suggest you is to use dictionary with arrays...like each and every array should be stored in the dictionary with respective key

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are trying to insert all non-duplicated characters from a firstname in the Frstname array, change this:

```
    //check
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *row in personarray) {
    [tempArray addObject:[row valueForKey:@"FirstName"]];

    for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]-1; i++){
        char alphabet = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
        NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
        if (![Frstname containsObject:uniChar]){  
            [Frstname addObject:uniChar];
        }
    }

}
```

for this:

```
    //check
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *row in personarray) {
    [tempArray addObject:[row valueForKey:@"FirstName"]];

    for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]-1; i++){
        char alphabet = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] '%c'", alphabet];
        NSArray *duplicates = [Frstname filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if ([duplicates count] == 0) {
            [Frstname addObject:uniChar];
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: in my database i have two value firstname and lastname i want display on table according to all firstname characters if i have a the print amit name, if i have b then print boby like this just like iphone phone directry display like that i want to display all name on table view

Comment: you can replace `uniChar` for `alphabet` of if you want it as string just replace `unichar` for `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet]`

Comment: Additionally, if you want something like the iphone phone directory you do not need the second for .. actually i would store a NSDictionary with key "A", "B", "C", etc.. then store an NSArray Object with all persons starting with "A", another NSArray with all persons starting with "B", etc.. instead of Frstname NSMutableArray.. thats nonsense to me..